# Querying nested objects not working

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a really basic question but I just cannot find what's wrong in my query.

The mapping:

```
     {
       "typeName": {
         "properties": {
             "active": {
                "type": "boolean"
             },
             "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
             },
             "values": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                "by": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "english"
                 },
                 "idChatRoom": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "english"
                 },
                 "message": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "english"
                 }
             }
          }
       }
```

As you can see there is a nested object called "values". If I try to run the following query:

```
     GET plugg_co/chatmessage_50813808/_search
     { 
       query: { 
          nested: {
             path: "values",
                query: {
                  filtered: {
                     filter: {
                        term: { "values.idChatRoom": "id-123" }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
     }
```

I don't get any result back (the index is not empty! I checked!). Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in nested query. Nested query is fine.But since `idChatRoom` is `analyzed` that's why you should not use `term query` on it.Instead you should use `match query`. Change you query to:

```
GET plugg_co/chatmessage_50813808/_search
{
"query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "values",
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "values.idChatRoom": "id-123"
        }
      }
    }
  } 
 }
```

If you want to use `term query` you can make it not analysed or `multifield`. You can refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/_multi_fields.html for more information on `multifield`
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I figured it was a problem with the analyzer. The point is that I want an exact match on the filter not a normal search match. If I use match query it will use an analyzer! Any suggestion? I remember there was a way to index "raw" value next to analyzed values for fields but I cannot find an example online. any suggestion?

Comment: Found the solution, I should have used a mapping for idChatRoom like this:       {
  "tweet" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "analyzed",
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
} and then use values.idChatRoom.raw in the query! my fault! it was a rookie mistake!